# Assasins Creed Revelations with Wine

Tags: 11.10, wine, games

I've got Ubuntu 11.10, now I want to install Assassins creed Revelations through Wine. Will it work bettter than on windows Xp ? Will it affect my system in dangerous way?: Is it risky ? Which version of Wine should I use for that ?  And if the game won't work properly, can I uninstall game and Wine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it work bettter than on windows Xp ?

Probably not.

> Will it affect my system in dangerous way?

No.

> Is it risky ?

No.

> Which version of Wine should I use for that ?

I would try the one from the Ubuntu archive.

> And if the game won't work properly, can I uninstall game and Wine ?

Yes.

Comment: Personally, my attempts to install games in Wine were not very successful, even for games marked "Gold" or "Platinum" in the Wine appdb.  AFAICs the trouble was with the open Intel video drivers not supporting the patented S3TC texture compression algorithm.  People with NVidia hardware and closed-source NVidia drivers seem to fare better with Windows games under Wine.